# Saving images with opencv and pyautogui interactively with the user

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui

I have the code below which I try to do the following:
Starts capturing the camera image but wanted to also display a dialog box containing a text field and an "ok" button, where the user must enter a value and pressing the "ok" button then scritp saves the image (jpg) naming it with the value that the user passed.

```
import cv2
import time
import pyautogui

camera_port = 0

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
camera.set(3, 1280)# set the resolution
camera.set(4, 1024)

emLoop = True

while (emLoop):

    retval, img = camera.read()
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('Foto', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(100)

    if k == 27:
        emLoop = False

    elif k == ord('s'):
        nome = input(pyautogui.prompt(text='Scanei o código.', title='Aviso:', default=''))
        cv2.imwrite(nome, img)

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Capture would always be active and as long as the user was entering the values and clicking "ok" would save the images, when the user clicked the "cancel" dialog box, would end the capture and terminate the script.
I'm trying to do this but unsuccessfully so far ... :(

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: the script is looped in the input, I tried to change the input to receive the user value but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try printing `k`.

Comment: as the script crashes after the user clicks the "ok" button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `pyautogui.prompt` opens a dialog box with a text field where the user can type something that will be returned. This is similar to how the function `input` works. Both have a string as an argument to be displayed as a prompt message to the user. The difference is that the former uses the terminal as the input interface instead of a dialog box.

It looks weird mixing them the way you are trying: `nome = input(pyautogui.prompt(...))`. It means like: Open a dialog box so the user can type a prompt message that will be displayed for himself in the console. After that, he types again something that will be returned to the `nome` variable.

Try either this:

```
nome = pyautogui.prompt(text='Scanei o código.', title='Aviso:', default='')
```

Or this:

```
nome = input('Aviso: Scanei o código.')
```